# Upload multiple imagen en un mismo campo

Tags: laravel

Necesito guardar las rutas de las imágenes en mi base de datos, en un campo llamado `img`, pero solo me guarda la primera ruta con el nombre de las imágenes seleccionada. Y lo que necesito es que ser guarden todas las rutas dentro de ese mismo campo, no solo una.

Mi Controllador

```
$data = $request->all();
    if($request->hasFile('img')){
        $destination_path = 'public/img';
        $imagen = $request->file('img');
        $img_name = $imagen->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = $request->file('img')->storeAs($destination_path, $img_name);

        $data[('img')] = $path;
    }
    $tramite = Tramite::create($data);
    return response()->json($tramite, 201);
```

Lo que devuelve mi var_dump($request->all())

```
array(1) {
    [
        "img"
    ]=>
  object(Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile)#305 (7) {
        [
            "test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private
        ]=>
    bool(false)
    [
            "originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private
        ]=>
    string(13) "nas-nasir.jpg"
    [
            "mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private
        ]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    [
            "error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private
        ]=>
    int(0)
    [
            "hashName":protected
        ]=>
    NULL
    [
            "pathName": "SplFileInfo":private
        ]=>
    string(23) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpBA1.tmp"
    [
            "fileName": "SplFileInfo":private
        ]=>
    string(10) "phpBA1.tmp"
    }
}
{}
```

Comment: No sé si entendí bien.. Entonces ¿en el request estás enviando múltiples imágenes?Podrías mostranos un dump de `$request->all()`? sobre todo lo que tenga en el elemento `img`.

Comment: Exacto, estoy enviando multiples imagenes. Actualice el post con el var_dump

Comment: ¿estás seguro que hay múltiples imágenes ahí? Sólo puedo ver una `nas-nasir.jpg`. Una vez que tengas un array, podrás iterar sobre él para guardar al disco y obteniendo las rutas donde se van guardando . Pregunto, porque para que php convierta a un array a los valores de un input, generalmente al nombre del input se le agregan corchetes al final, por ej `'img[]'`. Puedes ver en este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39846856/7498116) un ejemplo (está en inglés, pero el código muestra claramente a lo que me refiero)

Comment: Si, hay multiples archivos que los cargo desde Postman con la opción de files, pero no logro entender tampoco porque en el array solo aparece uno. Respecto a lo que me pasaste en el mi input en mi frontend(angular) tiene la etiqueta name='img[]'

Comment: Cuand envías desde postmam, el nombre del campo también debe tener los corchetes. Igual, prueba iterar sobre `$request->file('img')` y ve si guarda todos los archivos en el disco o sólo uno

Comment: Muestra una captura de pantalla de cómo cargas los archivos en Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolverlo! Dejo el código por si algún día alguien se encuentra en la misma situación.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{    
    $values = $request->except('img');
    $data = $request->only('img');
    if($request->hasFile('img')){
        foreach($request->file('img') as $image){
            $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move('storage\img', $name);
            $data[] = $name;
        }
    }
    
    $tramite = new Tramite;
    $tramite = Tramite::create($values);
    $tramite->img = json_encode($data);
    $tramite->save();

    return response()->json($tramite, 201);

}
```